# How to check Variable A affects Variable B?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I was analyzing the Moore dataset in the carData package, and I wanted to see the whether partner.status affects conformity or not.

```
set.seed(200)
library(carData)  
library(ggplot2)
```

And then using `ggplot`, I plotted the two variables using boxplot.

[image: plotted]

```
ggplot(data = Moore, aes (x = partner.status, y = conformity )) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

The plot only tells that those who have high status have high conforming responses and those with low status have lower median conforming responses.

Question: how to show that there’s evidence that partner.status affects conformity? What statistical methods do I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boxplot is a great start, it gives you an idea of what results you should expect.

Now, you need to find out if data is normally distributed (`shapiro.test(Moore$conformity))` ), and has homoscedastic variance (`fligner.test(Moore$conformity ~ Moore$partner.status)` read as conformity by partner.status). You can read about the p-values [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value), and make a conlcusion.

There are tons of other tests, these two are quite robust for this purpose.

Now, assuming you have normality and homoscedasticity you can do a t-test. 
If, you have normality and heteroscedasticity you can do a oneway.test. If you don't have normality you can use the Kruskal-Wallis test.

Now, analysing the output of one of those tests you can reject or not reject the hypothesis of equal means.

Comment: thanks for that. can equal means tell us the effect of one variable on the other?

Comment: If two groups have equal means when it's only explained by one other variable then this variable has 0 effect on the variable you wish to predict. 

You can test also test for correlation. cor.test(Moore$conformity, as.integer(Moore$partner.status))

Comment: Right. what about if I fit a regression model lm(partner.status~conformity, data = Moore) and get partner.stat = 1.97 - 0.04* conformity. From this, can we say partner.status affects conformity?

Comment: You can already say that partner.status influence conformity from the previous tests. A correlation of anything other than 0 also shows an influence (this is exactly what correlation is). If you however wish to use the linear regression you have your model flipped, you should change the position of the vectors. Then you can wrap summary() around the whole thing and use p-value again. Here you will also get an R-squared value, the higher this is the better. R-squared tells you how much of the data is explained by this exact linear model.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 groups for partner status (low and high). Conformity is a continuous dependent variable. I recommend an independent samples t-test.

Check and make sure you do not violate any assumptions.

Relevant information: 
https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/independent-t-test-statistical-guide.php

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is that also possible to use regression to see the effect of partner.status on conformity? can I fit a model lm(conformity~partner.status, data = Moore) to see the effect?

Comment: It is possible to use categorical variables (partner status) in regression.

This might be helpful:
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/faq/coding-systems-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-analysis-2/